# How to add String Array to tab layout and remove the existing items in tab layout in android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Am having Tab layout with the set of 11 items. I need to remove the existing items from the tab layout and need show only the selected item say for example only 4 items instead of 11.Below is my code.am having my selected items in(str) "String [] str = constants.selectedCategories;" All that i need to do now is i need to set a tablayout with the items in Str.How can i achieve this.

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Below is viewpagerAdapter code

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FashionFragment();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new JewelFragment();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            fragment = new RestaurantFragment();
        } else if (position == 3) {
            fragment = new SuperMarketFragment();
        } else if (position == 4) {
            fragment = new HomeApplianceFragment();
        } else if (position == 5) {
            fragment = new MobileStoreFragment();
        } else if (position == 6) {
            fragment = new MotorFragment();
        } else if (position == 7) {
            fragment = new ConstructionElectricalFragment();
        } else if (position == 8) {
            fragment = new SalonFragment();
        } else if (position == 9) {
            fragment = new BakeryFragment();
        }
        else if (position == 10) {
            fragment = new OtherFragment();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 11;
    }


   @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            title = "Fashion";
        } else if (position == 1) {
            title = "Jewellery";
        } else if (position == 2) {
            title = "Restaurant";
        } else if (position == 3) {
            title = "Super Market";
        } else if (position == 4) {
            title = "Home Appliance";
        } else if (position == 5) {
            title = "Mobile & Computer accessories";
        } else if (position == 6) {
            title = "Motors";
        } else if (position == 7) {
            title = "Construction & Electricals";
        } else if (position == 8) {
            title = "Saloon & Spa";
        } else if (position == 9) {
            title = "Bakkery & Sweets";
        }
        else if (position == 10) {
            title = "Others";
        }
        return title;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post out the code of ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: @Aman Jain.. Just now added. Kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest you to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of
>   `FragmentPagerAdapter` as the number of fragment in your viewpager is
>   not static and there are a large number of fragment pages.

You need to pass a list of fragment and its name in constructor of ViewPagerAdapter and whenever you want to add or remove fragment you just have to remove or add the fragment from list and notify the adapter.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
private ArrayList<String> fragmentName;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<Fragment> list) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragmentList = list;
    this.fragmentName = name;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentName.get(position);

}
public void addTab(Fragment fragment, String name) {

        fragmentList.add( fragment);
        fragmentName.add( name);

}

public void removeTab(int position) {
    fragmentList.remove(position);
    fragmentName.remove(position);
}
} 

ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList;
fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragmentList.add(new Fashion());
fragmentList.add(new Jewellery());
fragmentList.add(new Restaurent());
.....

ArrayList<String> name;
name = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("Fashion");
            add("Jewellery");
            add("Restaurent");
           .....

        }
    };
```

**Initialize ViewPager**

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),name,fragmentList);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**Add a fragment**

```
viewPagerAdapter.addTab(new Motors(),"Motors");
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Remove a fragment**

```
viewPagerAdapter.removeTab(3);
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```